# Why can I compare sbyte to all the other numeric types *except* ulong?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

You can do >, <, ==, etc. comparisons between sbyte and byte, int, uint, short, ushort, long, double, and float.  But not ulong.

My brain is exploding.  Can anyone explain why sbyte can be compared to uint but **not** ulong?

```
public bool sbyte_ulong_compare(sbyte x, ulong y)
{
    return x < y;  // compiler error CS0019
}
```

Also, using `unchecked` doesn't make things work any better.  Brain melting.

Another edit.  This works:

```
public bool sbyte_ulong_compare(sbyte x, ulong y)
{   
    //
    // returns x < y
    //
    if (x < 0)
        return true;

    if (y > 127)
        return true;

    return ((long)x < (long)y);
}
```

Comment: Good question! But, for those of us who haven't tried it, what happens when you try the comparison? In what way *can't* you compare those types (throws exception, won't compile, etc...)?

Comment: @djacobson: The compiler spits out `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'sbyte' and 'ulong'`  At least it does in VS2k8 in a .NET 3.5 project.

Comment: I added a short code snippet.

Comment: Re: `unchecked` - assuming [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx) is the keyword you're referring to, it suppresses overflow checking, nothing to do with invalid boolean comparisons.

Comment: @djacobson: Yeah.  I figured, eh, maybe magic will happen.  :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

dthorpe and Jon's answers are close but not quite correct.

The correct reasoning is as follows.

The specification states:

> For an operation of the form x op y,
>   where op is a comparison operator,
>   overload resolution is
>   applied to select a specific operator
>   implementation.

OK, what are the operator implementations that overload resolution has to work with?  They are:

```
bool operator <(int x, int y);
bool operator <(uint x, uint y);
bool operator <(long x, long y);
bool operator <(ulong x, ulong y);
bool operator <(float x, float y);
bool operator <(double x, double y);
bool operator <(decimal x, decimal y);
```

Plus the enum less-than operator for all enumerated types, plus the lifted-to-nullable versions of each of the foregoing.

Overload resolution must first eliminate *inapplicable* operators, and then from the remaining set of applicable operators, determine the *best* operator.

The int, uint, long and enum operators (and their lifted forms) are all eliminated because ulong does not implicitly convert to those types.

The uint and ulong operators (and their lifted forms) are all eliminated because sbyte does not implicitly convert to those types.

That leaves

```
bool operator <(float x, float y);
bool operator <(double x, double y);
bool operator <(decimal x, decimal y);
```

and their lifted forms.  We must now determine the *best* operator from those six.

What do we mean by "best"? When comparing two operators, the one with the *more specific* operand types is the better one.  By "more specific" I mean that "Tiger" is more specific than "Animal" because all Tigers are convertible to Animal but not all Animals are convertible to Tiger.

Clearly the unlifted forms are better than all of the corresponding lifted forms. A non-nullable type is more specific than its corresponding nullable type because a non-nullable type is always convertible to its nullable type, but not vice-versa. We can eliminate the lifted forms.

That leaves three.  Which of those three is the best?

float is more specific than double. Every float is convertible to double, but not every double is convertible to float.  Therefore double is eliminated.  That leaves two.

```
bool operator <(float x, float y);
bool operator <(decimal x, decimal y);
```

Which of these is the best? There is no implicit conversion from float to decimal. There is no implicit conversion from decimal to float. Therefore neither is better than the other.

Therefore no best operator can be determined. Overload resolution fails.

We have decided to report a generic error message that simply says that there is no such operator that does what you want, rather than giving the seemingly bizarre and confusing error message "operator overload resolution failed because float is neither better nor worse than decimal".  I think that is a reasonable design choice.

Comment: This answer is amazing.  Thank you!

Comment: What a good job we have `decimal` to make this fail. The thought of `ulong` and `long` being converted to `float` for comparisons is horrific, giving clearly inappropriate results. I would imagine that if we didn't have `decimal` here, we'd really have to have other rules to prevent this from happening.

Comment: The last step looks wrong.  The conversion is from sbyte/ulong to float or decimal.  Not between float and decimal.  It fails because neither is 'better'.  Compare CS0121.  Also doesn't need the iffy double elimination.

Comment: @Hans: The last step is right. Follow along: we have two operators: o1: float comparison, o2: decimal comparison. We have four conversions: C11: sbyte to float, C12: ulong to float, C21: sbyte to decimal, C22: ulong to decimal. For o1 to be better than o2 then either C11 has to be better than C21, or C21 has to be better than C22. Is C11 better than C21? For C11 to be better than C21, it must be the case that float is more specific than decimal. Is float more specific than decimal? Well, does float convert to decimal but decimal not convert to float? No. C11 is not better than C21.

Comment: By similar logic, C21 is not better than C11, C12 is not better than C22, and C22 is not better than C21. Since no conversion is better than the other, no best operator can be determined. The relevant question is "which destination type is more specific?" and that question is answered by considering the conversions between the destination types. **One conversion from a source type to a target type is better than another based on the convertibility of the target types to each other.**

Comment: I shouldn't argue but can't help myself.  If there are operator overloads available, do these rules suddenly change?  Selecting the right overload is a function overload resolution problem.  Starting out by assuming these overloads are implicitly available keeps the outcome consistent.  Not saying it works that way (I don't know), just how I would do it.

Comment: @Hans: Sections 7.3.4 and 7.3.5 describe the rules. First we determine the candidate set of user-defined operators. If that candidate set is empty then the predefined operator set is used instead. Operator overload resolution then happens on the chosen candidate set. (FYI in practice the actual rules for how overload resolution proceeds on *enum* types is not *exactly* as stated in the spec; there are subtle problems with the spec in this area which we hope to correct in future editions.)

Comment: 7.2.6 is interesting: "Numeric promotion is not a distinct mechanism, but rather an effect of applying overload resolution to the predefined operators."

Comment: @EricLippert: If for every instance of T there exists a U to which it may be converted, and that U is produced only by that T, and for every U there exists a T to which it may be converted, but some values of T may be produced by multiple values of U, it seems odd to refer to T as the "more specific" type.  If casting rules allow only implicit casts from T to U, but not vice versa, that would suggest not that T is more specific, but rather that the casting rules allow implicit casts only from the less-specific type to the more-specific one.

Answer (score 7):

When you compare two integers of different integer types, the type of the operation is the smallest integer type that can represent the full range of both operands combined.  If you compare a signed byte with a uint, the type of the operation is long, because long has enough range to cover the negative portion of the signed byte and the positive portion of the uint.

When you try to compare sbyte and ulong, there is no integer type that can span the ranges of both ulong and the negative portion of signed byte.  The compiler only considers built-in integer types. Implicitly promoting to Decimal is not included because Decimal is not an integer type, and for performance reasons.

In your 2nd code example, since you have prequalified the operands, you can safely typecast the operands to a common integer type that does not span the range of both operands.  Note also that in your 2nd example, you could typecast to byte (instead of long) with no loss of information since you have already established that the ulong value is less than 127 and the sbyte value is non-negative.

The C# compiler does not "see" that you have prequalified the operands and that logically the values in the operands are within the byte range, and the compiler does not generate code to perform such prequalifications itself.

Some languages do emit prequalifying code similar to your 2nd example to support comparisons between types that don't have a common superset type.  You take a performance and memory (size of code) hit for this.  C# probably doesn't emit this kind of prequalifying code in the spirit of not wanting to "reward" bad coding practices.  If you're comparing a signed value and a ulong, you need to be aware of and take responsibility for the costs.

In language theory there is a branch of type inferencing called (I think) type algebra which does track the tests against variables and dynamically narrows the range of the variable's type as new constraints are discovered in the flow of the code.  This form of type inferencing would allow you to compare the operands without typecasting in your 2nd example because it would see that you have prequalified the operands into the byte range.  C# doesn't do this kind of type inferencing.  I think Haskell or F# might.

Comment: +1 Great answer, very complete. I assumed you meant "Haskell" at the end there and not "Hascal", unless there's a strange Pascal variant I can't find via Google. :) Also, this would be even better if you had a citation for this statement: *"implicitly promoting to Decimal is not included for performance reasons."*

Comment: Yes, Haskell.  Damned phonetics. :P

Comment: The Decimal type favors completeness/precision over performance. Integer types compile down to hardware register values on the native CPU. Decimal does not. Therefore, Decimal will never provide the same level of runtime performance as the integer types. Decimal does define an implicit conversion from integer, but that will only be considered by the compiler when one of the operands in an expression is Decimal.  The C# compiler does not consider Decimal to be an integer type.

Comment: Note that the "Decimal is not considered for performance reasons" is not an absolute. Turbo Pascal & Delphi restricted operations combining signed and unsigned types for a long time "for performance reasons" but eventually the compiler work was done to emit the code necessary to safely support mismatched range comparisons.  I doubt that C# will change this aspect any time soon, but when they start running out of squeaky wheels to address, who knows? ;>

Comment: This is a really good answer.  I'm torn.  Jon Skeet is Jon Skeet, but your answer is impressively comprehensive and understandable.  I'm going with my gut!

Comment: Close, but no cigar. Your argument about decimal being not an integer type is specious. See my answer for details.